# Analytically compare two 3D heatmaps of the brain

Tags: inverse-problems, image-processing

I have two heatmaps of a 3D model of the brain, with the color of each pixel being an intensity of the response to a stimulus, and I want to get a metric of how "alike" those two heatmaps are, what can I use? In this picture you can see an example (2D projection) of a heatmap I want to analyze

[image: Here's an example of a heatmap]

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/q/25037/11260